# How to to run eslint on *.js.erb files?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, eslint

I'd like to lint the files in my rails project (ideally, in my editor while making edits) via [eslint](http://eslint.org/), but I am currently unable to lint files that are pre-processed with ERB.

How can I include *.js.erb files in the linting process?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to run eslint with `-ext js.erb` flag. If your files contain more then just javascript, however, you will have to create your own plugin with processor, that would strip out everything but pure javascript and maintain source map, so that error messages can be changed to point to correct line numbers after linting. You can see more information about processors here: http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins#processors-in-plugins

Comment: I am using eslint version 4.19.0 and the flag has to be `--ext js.erb` with two dashes.